# Are analytic functions that approach zero at infinity part of $L^p (\mathbf{C}) $

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, normed-spaces

This might be a bit of an obvious question. I'm studying the normal solutions to the Beltrami equation, and I have that $f_z - 1$ approaches zero as $z \rightarrow \infty$.
Apparently it is then true that $f_z - 1 \in L^p (\mathbf{C})$ for $p > 2$. I just wondered why exactly this is.

A couple of guesses I have are:

Applying Louivilles theorem gives us that $f_z -1$ equals zero, which is clearly part of $L^p (\mathbf{C})$.

All functions which decay at infinity have convergent integrals over $\mathbf{C}$ (this is probably not true, but maybe I'm wrong)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: A sufficient condition for $g$ to be in $L^p(\mathbb C)$ is that $$\lvert g(z)\rvert^p=O(\lvert z \rvert^{-2-\epsilon}), \quad \lvert z \rvert \to \infty.$$ Maybe your $g(z)=f_z-1$ satisfies this? I don't know. It is certainly not the case that "All functions which decay at infinity have convergent integrals over C".

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let me clear up few things: Liouvilles equation is a PDE, however, its solutions are not necessarily analytic functions. So $\partial_{\bar{z}}f \neq 0$ in general and hence $f$ isn't analytic/holomorphic and so Liouvilles theorem doesn't apply.

In general, you have that $g \in L^p(\mathbb{C})$ does not imply $\lim_{|z| \to \infty}g=0$ for any $p \geq 1$. This can be seen, even if you assume your function to be smoothy, by adding infinitely many bumps at infinity.

However, what I suspect is that you want to use a result like this: If $|d(f-z)| \in L^p(\mathbb{C})$ for $p>2$, with $d$ being the differential and so
$$
d(f-z)=f_{\bar{z}}+f_z-1=(\mu+1)f_z-1 
$$
by using the Beltrami equation, then we have
$$
\lim_{|z| \to \infty}f-z=0.
$$
This is a result on Sobolev spaces. I just wanted to leave this comment, since it is technically not an answer to your questions, but might give you some pointers.

If you provide a bit more context, a better answer could be given I think.